# Wie wird diese Konstruktion genannt: "Ich habe schon eines."

Tags: word-usage

> Möchten Sie ein Glas Wasser?
>   Nein, danke. Ich habe schon eines.

"Eines", eine unbekannte Form Akkusativ seiend.

Comment: Anmerkung: Deine Frage klingt wie eine fast wörtliche Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Mögliche deutsche Formulierungen wären zum Beispiel "Wie wird diese Konstruktion genannt?" oder "Wie nennt man diese Konstruktion?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Einer" ist ein so genanntes Indefinitpronomen. "Ich habe schon eines" ist keine besondere Konstruktion, genauso wenig wie "Ich habe schon ein Haus" oder "Ich habe schon aus."

Edit:

Das Indefinitpronomen wird "einer/eine/eines" dekliniert, indes der unbestimmte Artikel "ein/eine/ein". Der unbestimmte Artikel muss aber immer vor einem Nomen stehen: "Ich habe schon **ein** Glas." Wenn kein Nomen folgt, wird das Indefinitipronomen verwendet: "Ich habe schon eines." Der Artikel "ein" entspricht z.B. englisch "a":

> I have **a** glass already.

Das Indefinitpronomen "einer/eine/eines" entspricht dem englischen "one":

> Do you want a glass of water?
>
> I have **one** already

Comment: Aber warum ist es nicht "ein"?

Comment: Ich habe gelernt, dass im Plural es als "welche, welche, welchen, welcher" dekliniert wird. "N., Akk., D., G." Zum Beispiel: "Ich brauche noch Salz! Hast du noch welches?" «Aber "das gilt nur für Dinge, da Personen immer "zählbar" sind». Wie würdest du das sagen, wenn man sich auf Menschen in Plural bezieht?

Comment: @user135711: *Während die Kunden die Bekleidungsgeschäfte überrannten, kamen kaum welche in die Bücherläden.* Das ist ein völlig korrekter Satz.

Comment: @guidot Ich verstehe jetzt. Ich habe auch das falsche Beispiel für Plural benutzt: "Gibst du mir noch ein paar Äpfel?"
  - "Ja, hier hast du du."